# Generating a matrix of multiple random variables

Tags: random, spss, chi-squared

I need to generate 10 million values (Bernoulli and Poisson) for my end of year project and since the .csv file I use as a support is limited at 32K values per column, that makes it incredibly tedious to generate 10M values since that would take me 300 variables, which, while not impossible to make (that would take what, 20 minutes ?), must not be the only way to proceed. Is there any way I could generate 300 variables at once ?

Answer (score 0):

```
dataset close all.
*this is to create a new dataset.
DATA LIST /NEWVAR 1.
BEGIN DATA
1
END DATA.

*this will create 300 variables and 32000 lines.
vector d(300).
LOOP varx=1 TO 32000.
        loop #i = 1 to 300.
        compute d(#i) = uniform(1). /*use whatever generation method you want here.
        end loop.
XSAVE OUTFILE='somepath\temp.sav' .
END LOOP.
EXECUTE.
get file ='somepath\temp.sav'.
```